# concat pdf pages after pdfcrop

Tags: pdf

I ran [`pdfcrop`](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) to crop the whitespace from pdf. As expected, the result is a pdf with pages of varying sizes. Is there any way to "squash" all these pages so they nicely fit in A4 (or any other format) avoiding whitespace?

I want to do this so if I have a pdf with lot's of whitespace I can `pdfcrop` it and when I run `pdfnup` I don't end up with a very sparse document.

For example, if I want to print to A4 (21cm height) and my pdf after `pdfcrop` has pages with heights like these:

- Page 1: 10cm
- Page 2: 5cm
- Page 3: 10cm
- Page 4: 13cm
- Page 5: 4cm

i can save some whitespace by printing them like these:

- NewPage 1=Page 1 + 2 => 15cm
- NewPage 2=Page 3 => 10cm
- NewPage 3=Page 4 + 5 => 17cm